# Need to open a jquery modal from a flash movie

Tags: jquery, flash

I have a flash carousel with products. The products are being loaded from a xml file. 
When you click on a product in the carousel a dialog modal needs to popup.

im using in the flash geturl function. But what should i put in here? got to be something like 
`javascript:openFunction()`
but this doesnt work, anyone have some ideas?

and what should i write for the openFunction() in my jquery file?.

I dont need the complete script, just a step in the right direction is fine too :)

Thnx

Answer (score 4):

The most common is to use the **ExternalInterface** to call javascript functions:

Actionscript :

```
ExternalInterface.call('popupMessage','hello');
```

Javascript :

```
function popupMessage(msg)
{
    alert(msg);
}
```

**Documentation :**
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html

If this doesn't work either you may at least be able to catch the errors and debug it easier than getUrl (you are working in as2, right?).